# How To Protect Phpmyadmin Database on Localhost

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

A software is installed to run locally on client's computer. How does one prevent someone going directly to localhost/phpmyadmin and tinkering with saved values in the db. I know one can protect the whole phpmyadmin with password, but this can still be found out from the folder. How does one protect individual database/tables.

Comment: What kind of webserver are you using? Maybe you can try to block others  by configure the webserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

phpMyAdmin is just a GUI for MySQL databases. You can remove it completely without affecting your application.

- Step 1: Remove phpMyAdmin (not MySQL)
- Step 2: Change MySQL username and/or password.

Answer (score -1):

add this to your apache configure file which related to phpmyadmin

```
    Order deny,allow
    allow from 127.0.0.1
    deny from all
```

The code above means only localhost have the permission to access phpmyadmin.

Comment: This won't protect from some user logged into the same computer to access http://localhost/phpmyadmin.